# pytest: get current parametrize value from request fixture

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I have a fixture that I want to apply to every test function, where I extract metadata from the tests. Something like

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def extract_metadata(request):
    func_name = request.function.__name__
    # etc.
    ...
```

I also want to extract the parametrize values here. But I can't figure out how to extract the current parameter values from the `request` object. The only place I see that they are indicated at all is in the test id inside of the `request.node.name`, but I'd prefer to extract the actual values rather than parsing them out of the id in the string.

Comment: You could check: `request.node.callspec._idlist` and/or `request.node.originalname`

Comment: @dosas `_idlist` is the string id, not the actual parameter inputs. Like I said, I'd like to access the data directly rather than trying to parse string ids. The `originalname` doesn't seem to contain parameter data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters can be accessed with `request.node.callspec.params`, which is a dict mapping parameter name to parameter value.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was searching for!